# Chrome's alert window - cropped?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

We're experiencing an inconsistent behaviour (cropping) with Chrome's [alert window](http://jsbin.com/xixoqogavi/1/edit?output) :

([*fiddle for testing*](http://jsbin.com/xixoqogavi/1/edit?output))

- My PC at work (windows 7) ,chrome 52:

[image]

- Another PC at work (windows 7) - chrome 52 :

[image]

- My PC at home (windows 10) ,chrome 52:

[image]

**Question**

What is the *reason* for this crop ( any setting to change in windows/chrome?)

We're only after the reason.

Comment: I have never seen this before in any version of Chrome on any version of Windows. I suspect your system, not a problem with the code.

Comment: @CodyGray I didn't mention anything about code here. I'm after the windows/chrome settings reason

Comment: It is not a "setting". There is something wrong with your system, or you have some kind of extension installed that is responsible.

Comment: @CodyGray it's not only on my PC. I've disabled all chrome's plugins and still.... on some computers it does crop and some not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found it.**

When my settings are (and they are):

[image]

Then I do see crop :

[image]

But if I change the settings into "let windows choose" :

[image]

Then I Don't see the crop :

[image]